# How load external svg in css section in Vue

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I need to load external svg image in css section of my Vue component. I have vue.config.js file which shown below:

```js
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false,
  chainWebpack: config => {
    const svgRule = config.module.rule('svg');
    svgRule.uses.clear();

    svgRule
      .oneOf('external')
        .resourceQuery(/\?external/)
        .use('file')
          .loader('file-loader')
          .options({
            name: 'assets/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
          })
          .end()
          .end()
      .oneOf('inline')
          .include
          .add(path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/svg'))
          .end()
        .use('vue-svg-loader')
          .loader('vue-svg-loader')
          .end()
          .end()
  }
};
```

All works good when i load svg image from html template like this.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <img src="@/components/svg/close-icon.svg?external" alt="" />
    </div>
</template>
```

That way i can see than in network tab of DevTools file loads with hash and i can see it on the page.
But when i try to load it through css section of component, it fails. Firstly, i can't set path with `@` like `'@/components/svg/close-icon.svg?external`, vue show error message that module not found. So i try `'/src/components/svg/close-icon.svg?external` path. You can see it below.

```
<template>
  <button>Button</button>
</template>

...

<style lang="sass" scoped>
button
    background: url('/src/components/svg/check-icon.svg?external')
</style>
```

Now vue don't throw error, but i see in DevTools that path to file haven't hash and looks like `http://localhost:8080/src/components/svg/check-icon.svg?external`, so file can't load. How i can configure webpack to load external svg images from css section.

Comment: Try using the relative path "./svg/check-icon.svg?external" this will help webpack.

Comment: thanks, it works, but i thought there are a better way to use it, with `@` symbol for absolute path if i will separate components and put them in internal folder. But for some reason it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of the `css-loader`:

> To import assets from a node_modules path (include resolve.modules)
>   and for alias, prefix it with a ~:
>
> ```
> url(~module/image.png) => require('module/image.png')
> url('~module/image.png') => require('module/image.png')
> url(~aliasDirectory/image.png) => require('otherDirectory/image.png')
> ```

Comment: it's can used for import assets from a node_modules path, but not for folder src, which i need. https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#url-transform-rules

Comment: I thought you were using an alias... `@` is an folder alias.